# How to convert to a int add 3 and then display the new number as a string

Tags: python

I have made variables and defined them, now I need help. I started with making an int(input("")
but I got to the if statement, and idk how to get it to convert it to a number so that I could add 3 to it for picking that particular class.

i tred to int(willpower) to convert it but it said it cant display it because its a int not a string. do i need to do this int(willpower) + 3 str(willpower)? convert it from a int add 3 and then convert it back?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You have to be more specific about the question you ask, better if you can post the code here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.